# window switching not working when used from a plugin

Tags: vim

I'm using a filetype plugin that automatically splits the window and then tries to switch to the lower window.
The plugin code looks like this:

```
:1sp
wincmd j
```

While this works well when entered in command-line mode it fails to switch windows after the split when being run in a plugin.
The same symptoms manifest when using

```
normal ^W^W
```

instead of wincmd j. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement `:help preview-window`?

Comment: No. I'm trying to keep the column headers visible when editing tabular data as suggested at http://alangrow.com/blog/turn-vim-into-excel-tips-for-tabular-data-editing

Comment: It should work fine so you should show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: The whole plugin code is quoted in the question and should allow reproducing the issue.